# How to use mnemonic to recovery my ethereum wallet

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, web3j, encryption, bip39

I use web3j to create my ethereum wallet.the Code just like down

```
import org.web3j.crypto.Bip39Wallet;
import org.web3j.crypto.Credentials;
import org.web3j.crypto.ECKeyPair;
import org.web3j.crypto.WalletUtils;

wallet = WalletUtils.generateBip39Wallet(password, new File(keystorePath));
// keystore's file name
String keystoreFileName = wallet.getFilename();
// my mnemonic
String mnemonic = wallet.getMnemonic();
```

I can use this code get my address

```
Credentials credentials = WalletUtils.loadBip39Credentials(password, mnemonic);
String address = credentials.getAddress();
```

I can import my wallet by this:

```
Credentials credentials = WalletUtils.loadBip39Credentials(password, mnemonic);
```

but in this way I need `password` & `mnemonic`,How I import or recovery my wallet by `mnemonic` without `password`,because some wallet app just like metamask or imtoken , they don't need the **old** `password` that I create my wallet and the can reset a **new** `password`.

In other words,recovery or import the wallet just need `mnemonic`,how I do it by web3j

[image]

**Is ereryone can tell me how to do it by web3j.thank u very much.**

Comment: I think the `password` is new password as shown in your metamask screen shot

Comment: yes.Just need `mnemonic` and u can set a `new password`.It's meaning that I can reset my wallet just by `mnemonic`

Comment: Ah, I mean the `password` in `WalletUtils.loadBip39Credentials(password, mnemonic);` also new password, not the current password then you user can input any new password to recover the wallet

Comment: @HaĐANG right.I want to get it `you user can input any new password to recover the wallet ` but now my user recover the wallet need `password`

Answer (score 5):

For Bip44 wallets Web3j will use the derivation path `m/44/60'/0'/0`. The more commonly used path is `m/44/60'/0'/0/0` (with an extra `/0`).

The following code will derive the correct address given a valid mnemonic.

```
String mnemonic = "abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon about";
String password = "";
byte[] seed = MnemonicUtils.generateSeed(mnemonic, password);
Bip32ECKeyPair masterKeypair = Bip32ECKeyPair.generateKeyPair(seed);
final int[] path = {44 | HARDENED_BIT, 60 | HARDENED_BIT, 0 | HARDENED_BIT, 0, 0};
Bip32ECKeyPair childKeypair = Bip32ECKeyPair.deriveKeyPair(masterKeypair, path);
Credentials credential = Credentials.create(childKeypair);

System.out.println(credential.getAddress());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that only is password of Metamask, it is not used for wallet encryption.
You can recovery wallet with bip39 package:

https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bip39

```
let seed = await bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonicPhrase, password); //password can null
let HDwallet = await etherHDkey.fromMasterSeed(seed);
let wallet = HDwallet.derivePath(hdPath + "/" + index).getWallet();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need password if you have 12 words simply visit https://iancoleman.io/bip39/
Paste your recovery words it will extract Address with private key

Comment: A comment that it is much safer to run it offline: https://github.com/iancoleman/bip39#standalone-offline-version

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the bip44 encryption protocol to generate mnemonics and recover wallets.
Because imtoken and metamask wallets operate based on the bip44 protocol.
If you use the bip39 protocol, the result will be different from that of imtoken and metamask.
Also note that imtoken and metamask do not specify a password.
Refer to the following example code

```
            Credentials credentials = Bip44WalletUtils.loadBip44Credentials("", "you mnemonic");
        String address = credentials.getAddress();
```